# GDB + CLion + STM32 - won't remote debug

Tags: gdb, stm32, clion, gdbserver

I read through [GDB Monitor commands in CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810593/gdb-monitor-commands-in-clion) providing good insight, but I am having a slightly different issue:

My environment:

- Target: ARM Cortex M4 (STM32F401RE)
- ST-UTIL gdb server (https://github.com/texane/stlink)
- arm-none-eabi-gdb 7.7.1+dfsg-5+8~bpo8+1
- CLion 2016.3.2 Build #CL-163.10154.43
- Debian 8

In the GDB Remote Debug config panel, I've set:

```
GDB:         /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb
Symbol file: /home/malachi/temp/mbed_test/mbed-os-program/BUILD/NUCLEO_F401RE/GCC_ARM/mbed-os-program.elf
```

From CLion, no matter what I do, I consistently get this for Console:

```
Cannot configure GDB defaults: No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Debugger connected to localhost:4242
```

I've tried brute forcing 'file' with a .gdbinit but gdbinit seems ignored

Furthermore, it *does* indicate a connection to st-util running remotely, but I am **unable to execute any commands (breakpoints, stepping, pause, etc)** except for terminate - which does seem to terminate it.

If I use arm-none-eabi-gdb direct from command line (`/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb` verified), things work as normal, breakpoints, stepping, etc.  Also .elf symbols load properly direct from command line.

Lastly, if I use configuration of `GDB: Default (Bundled)` I don't expect it to work well, but it actually gets further and allows a very limited functionality of pausing/resuming (but with absolutely no other abilities) and does not complain about the symbols

Comment: Have you read [this](http://tom-itx.no-ip.biz:81/~webpage/rue/tutorial.pdf)? Also, you should build your firmware with `-g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables -mapcs -mno-sched-prolog` flags in order to debug your FW with GDB with full functionality.

Comment: Also see [this](http://www.farrellf.com/projects/hardware/2012-06-18_Hardware_Debugging_with_GDB_and_the_STM32F4/).

Comment: Thanks for the insights.  No change in the problem, but your info should help stave off future issues.  I notice "-mapcs" is deprecated, and oddly - mbed OS debug profile "-fomit-frame-pointer" is explicitly enabled

Comment: In order to investigate it closer we need debug logs. May I ask you to create an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP and attach the logs as described here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206560589-Debugger-doesn-t-stop-on-a-breakpoint-Debugger-shows-Command-timed-out-What-to-do-. Alternatively you send the logs through our support channel: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to CLion 2016.3.3 resolves this issue.

I am experiencing some intermittent slowdown/connection issues but I can't be certain that it's a CLion thing.

Thank you Sam Protsenko and Eldar Abusalimov for your help in this.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar setup (except for CLion), and I'm able to debug my STM32 board via [STM32F4DISCOVERY](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html) (which has ST-LINK v2 on it). Perhaps if you follow my instructions, it will work out for you, too.

First of all, provide next flags to GCC when building your firmware:

```make
# Debug flags
CFLAGS  += -Os -g -fno-schedule-insns -fno-schedule-insns2

# Backtrace support
CFLAGS  += -fno-omit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables
CFLAGS  += -mapcs -mno-sched-prolog
LDFLAGS += -mapcs -mno-sched-prolog
```

Use next script for starting GDB server. Of course, [st-util](https://github.com/texane/stlink) must be installed, as that script uses it.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-
GDB=${CROSS_COMPILE}gdb

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Please provide elf-file for debug symbols" >&2
    exit 1
fi

elf_file="$1"

echo '---> Starting GDB server...'
if [ -f gdb.pid ]; then
    kill -9 $(cat gdb.pid)
    rm -f gdb.pid
fi
st-util & echo $! >gdb.pid

echo '---> Starting GDB...'
$GDB -ex "target extended localhost:4242" $elf_file
kill -9 $(cat gdb.pid)
rm -f gdb.pid
```

Save it as `gdb.sh` and run it like this (once you powered up your board):

```
$ ./gdb.sh your-firmware.elf
```

You'll see `(gdb)` prompt. Now you can use usual GDB commands for debugging. In my case, GDB shows me (on start):

```
GDB connected.

reset_handler () at ../../cm3/vector.c:68
68      for (src = &_data_loadaddr, dest = &_data;
```

So I'm usually do:

```
(gdb) break main
(gdb) continue
(gdb) list
```

And then use usual debugging commands, like `step`, `next`, `print var`, `bt`, etc. Everything works as expected.

Also it should be mentioned that I'm using [libopencm3](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3) in my firmware, so it also might have some influence over success of operation. I'd advice you to build and flash some simple example from [libopencm3-examples](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3-examples) (like [this one](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3-examples/tree/master/examples/stm32/f4/stm32f4-discovery/miniblink)), and try to debug it with GDB. If it works, and your code doesn't work with GDB, then you can easily look for difference and find the issue.

### References

[1] [Debugging details](http://www.farrellf.com/projects/hardware/2012-06-18_Hardware_Debugging_with_GDB_and_the_STM32F4/)

[2] [Using ST-LINK with st-util](http://tom-itx.no-ip.biz:81/~webpage/rue/tutorial.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the thought out response.  I've had some success (thankfully) already doing GDB-command-line-only operations, it was mainly CLion environment which didn't seem to be responding well